# Getting all records but if some of them are connected then getting only last one

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

example table

```
id | parentId | desc | date
1  |   null   | .... |  1
2  |   null   | .... |  2
3  |    1     | .... |  3
4  |    1     | .... |  4
5  |    2     | .... |  5
6  |   null   | .... |  6
7  |   null   | .... |  7
```

okay, now I want to get all records BUT if some of them are connected via id <-> parentId, then i want only the one with latest date. Result of the query for the table above shold be

```
id | parentId | desc | date
4  |    1     | .... |  4
5  |    2     | .... |  5
6  |   null   | .... |  6
7  |   null   | .... |  7
```

how can i do this in sqllite?

Comment: can u [fiddle the schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have API level 16 (Jelly Bean) or later, the following will work:

```
SELECT id,
       parentId,
       "desc",
       MAX(date) AS date
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY COALESCE(parentId, id)
```

In older Android versions, you must use a correlated subquery to filter out records with an earlier date:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM MyTable AS T2
                  WHERE COALESCE(T2.parentId,      T2.id     ) =
                        COALESCE(MyTable.parentId, MyTable.id)
                    AND T2.date > MyTable.date)
```